# Access date of Amazon s3 resources

Tags: amazon-s3

Anyone know of a way to ascertain the last accessed date for s3 files/buckets or if this is even recorded? Doesn't seem visible via the GUI and a basic try of s3cmd and boto shows last modified date but not accessed.

Comment: What kind of file system is thereon?

Comment: Hm? Referring to Amazon s3 file storage service.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; temporary confusion with EBS volumes.  More coffee.  Grunt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S3 does not hold so much information like file access time, since it is not even aware of the term "file", even if you can simulate it. S3 is an OBJECT STORAGE.

On the other hand, you can specify another bucket where to log what happens with your bucket and you will get an object created in that bucket for each action happening on the original one. You could use this to detect the last access time, however, there is a disclaimer from Amazon that the logs may be arriving shortly, late, out of order (well, they do have timestamps) or may not arrive at all in some very rare cases.

I hope this helps.